# increment map field if map exist in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am trying to save user weekly track in a serial map. Numbers from 1 to 7 represents days. Inside day map i hold timestamps and inside them there are counters.

What i want to achive is for example today is day 1 and my time stamp is 1658739600000 and i want to increase count. But if day is 1 and timestam is different then i want to change the timestamp with the new one and start count from 0. Can i achive this with this logic? I dont want to read and check data from user side if timestamp is same or different.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the [atomic increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) operation with the `.` syntax to [update nested fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

The exact syntax depends on your language (please, always specify that going forward), but in JavaScript it'd be something like this:

```
docRef.update(
    "serial.1.1658739600000", FieldValue.increment(1)
);
```

If you want to [delete a field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields), pass `FieldValue.delete()` for its new value. You can combine both instructions in a single call to the `update()` method.

Comment: Thans for your answer but this just adds new map field. I want to replace it with old timestamp if exist in same day.

Comment: If the `serial.1.1658739600000` field already exists, the above increments its value by 1. If it doesn't exist, the above creates the field with a value of 1. Is that not what is happening for you, or not what you want (in which case I might not understand your use-case).

Comment: I'm coding with flutter. Lets say serial.1.1658739600000.counter = 10 and i want to use different timestamp with same day and i want to delete serial.1.1658739600000.counter = 10 and it must replace with serial.1.newTimestamp.counter = 1. But with your code the old timestamp stay same

Comment: Are you asking how to delete a field? That would be by passing `FieldValue.delete()` as its new value. I added a paragraph on that to my answer.

Comment: I want to update a nested field without dot notation but with FieldValue.increment(1)

Comment: I'm not sure what that means: to update a nested field, you need to use dot notation. But why do you *not* want to use that? What ill-effect does using dot notation have for you?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have found a solution. I you still need the answer (or anyone do), here is something that could help.

```
String oldKey = 'serial.'+'index'+'.'+oldTimeStamp+'.count';
String newKey= 'serial.'+'index'+'.'+newTimeStamp+'.count';

docRef.update(
    oldKey , FieldValue.delete()
);
docRef.update(
   newKey, FieldValue.increment(1)
);
```